# Connect the bot to two voice channels (NodeJS discordJS)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

There are two voice channels and you need to broadcast the radio in one, and in the other the music that users want. There is no problem with this, but when the bot connects to the second channel, it leaves the first.

How to connect a bot to two voice channels at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry but I think that is not possible. The bot is a user as you are, can you connect to two voice channels at the same time?

Comment: It's a pity, the only way out is to create a second bot, which I didn't really want to do